# Какое наименьшее количество двоичных знаков потребуется для кодирования слова МОЛОКОСОС?

Tags: алгоритм, информатика, сжатие

По каналу связи передаются сообщения, содержащие только восемь букв: К, Л, М, Н, О, П, Р, С. Для передачи используется неравномерный двоичный код в котором никакой более короткий код не является началом более длинного кода. Кодовые слова для некоторых букв известны: К – 001, Н – 100, Р – 11 (каждой из остальных букв нужно назначить свой код).

я вот прикинул и составил для всех букв:

К – 001, Н – 100, Р – 11 , Л - 010 , М - 01 , О - 111 , П - 10 , С - 110

Comment: Код Хэмминга погуглите

Comment: У вас код для Р является началом для О, код для П - начало для Н, то же самое М и Л.

Comment: Рисуйте дерево.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При заданных условиях выходит 26 бит (строя дерево Хаффмана):

```
К  001 
Л  0000
М  00010
Н  100
О  01
П  00011
Р  11
С  101

00010010000010010110101101
```

Comment: это  вы решили через код Хэмминга?

Comment: Код Хаффмана - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0 - в уже имеющееся дерево для трех букв поместил как можно выше О, чуть ниже С, остальные - уже неважно, их по одной...

Comment: вы немного обсчитались)) не 25 , а 26

Comment: @gaak2309 Бывает и такое :)

Comment: @gaak2309 Зато если б не эти уже имеющиеся 3 буквы - то можно было бы до 19 снизить... Если опять не просчитался :)

Comment: я думаю вы все верно сделали)